# Is WSO2 / Mulesoft Identity Server Free for commercial purposes?

Tags: authentication, wso2, saml-2.0, identityserver3, accesscontrolservice

I am looking out for Authentication Broker products for integrating with multiple IDPs which has SAML2P, Ws-Fed based endpoints, ADFS/STS, Facebook, Google etc.

I am a .NET Developer and developing applications on .NET platform. Initially I thought to create a Auth. Broker by my own using Kentor AuthServices OR ComponentOne and WIF etc. But some of the folks mentioned about countertop products. Could you please help with best one , open source and good for .NET / MSFT platform Product integrations etc.

Note : I heard WSO2, Mulesoft is based on APACHE,JAVA etc. Seems like its hard for us to maintain those on our technology stack. Please comment....

Comment: WSO2 use Apache v2 license. check that.

Comment: Jorge infante Osorio : Could you please be specific ? So Do I need to spend some amount on Apache License ? As far I know, its free.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of the Mulesoft. But WSO2 products are licensed under apache license and you are free to use it for any commercial purposes.